# Xamarin Forms navigation page doesn't redirect my page correctly

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have couple of pages that I need to navigate to. I have a basic login page that when user enters correctly I'll be redirecting user to my home page. When I click the login button the page I wanted to wont appear in the screen.

```
if (Username == user.username && Password == user.password)
   {
      await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("successfully logged in", "", "Ok");
      await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
    }
```

This is where I'm trying to push my homepage to the screen but it's only visible when I click the back button of the emulator. I'm positive that the if block works because I can see my display alert that says successfully logged in. I've declared my MainPage as a NavigationPage in App.xaml.cs. It's really weird but can anyone help?

**Edit**

I have 4 pages that I navigate from or to them.

1. Main Page (where there is only 2 buttons to login or signup)
2. Login Page (single button to validate user and navigate to HomePage)
3. Signup Page (not important at the moment)
4. HomePage

Coming through the main page I used to have the codes in order to navigate in the MainPage.xaml.cs file :

```
private async void loginBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
    }
    private async void signUpBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new SignUpPage());
    }
```

After navigating successfully to the Login Page and entering correct username and password I tried to navigate and validate it in my LoginPageViewModel.cs which is here:

```
 private async void Login()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Please enter Email and Password", "OK");
        else
        {
            var user = await FirebaseHelper.GetUser(Username);
            if (user != null)
                if (Username == user.username && Password == user.password)
                {
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Successfully logged in", "", "Ok");
                    await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
                }
                else
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login Failed", "Please enter correct Email or Password", "OK");
            else
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login Failed", "User not found", "OK");
        }
    }
```

Then I thought maybe it's not working because I'm using `Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage())`
in some page but in the the other pages that I'm using something else which is: `App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());`

But that didn't solved my problem.

I posted my solution but I don't think it's permanent or correct but just gets me through this weird issue for now.

Comment: Might be an XF bug. **1)** As a test, does it work if you comment out the "DisplayAlert" line? **2)** Does HomePage appear okay if you make it the FIRST page the app shows (instead of showing the Login page).

Comment: It's still no good when I comment out the DisplayAlert. But HomePage appears when I make it the first page when the app opens.

Comment: **3)** Clarify one detail: After push "Ok" on Alert, what is visible on screen? Login page or blank screen? **4)** Add to question enough of the declaration of MainPage and LoginPage, to show how LoginPage appears.  App.xaml.cs: `MainPage = new NavigationPage(); PushAsync(new LoginPage());`? (not exact syntax...)

Comment: After pushing the OK button nothing happens, login page stays on the screen. But like I said when I clicked the back button on the emulator, my Homepage appears on the screen.

Comment: I understand. That is not normal behavior - what you show usually works without problem - so there may be code (not shown in question) causing this to happen. Would need to see the complete code that executes when the button (that leads to the code you show) is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed all the navigations using MVVM. You see, at the beginning of my app I wrote my Navigate.PushAsync() codes inside the button Clicked() methods in .xaml.cs files but when I used Command="{Binding *SomeCommandName*}" using ViewModel files the problem vanished. I didn't even changed anything in the related file. But still don't know why I couldn't use both ways at the same time.

Comment: no of course not on a single button. What I meant to say is I'm using Command="{Binding SomeCommandName}" and Binding this command in my ViewModel, rather than just giving the button a Clicked method and doing it behind in the xaml.cs file. That weirdly solved my problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

Given that HomePage is good if start on it, but `PushAsync` isn't working correctly, I suspect its an issue with **how** you get to the code you've shown. Would need to see the complete code from Button press to those lines of code, to say more.

**Work-Around:**

To make sure Xamarin Forms is "in a good state" to transition to new page: Wrap in BeginInvokeOnMainThread:

```cs
...
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("successfully logged in", "", "Ok");
    await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
});
```